# Inserting multiple rows to database from table rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a little problem with my code in PHP/SQL. I must insert data to database but with this method:

[image: Screen]

So I code this model to do this:

```
function sendPricings() {

            $datas = $this->input->post('checkbox');
            $data = array($this->input->post('checkbox'));

            if (!empty($datas)) {

            foreach($this->input->post('fvat') as $row){

                $data = array(
                    'fvat'          =>      $row,
                );

                    $this->db->insert('pricing_raports', $data);
                }
            }
        }
```

But this method didn't work.

Anybody can help me build working method or tell me how I can do this?
 I am using CodeIgniter2.x PHP Framework.

Comment: you can use in this `insert_batch` go throught this  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert

Comment: @Abbas new location for user guide from ellislab http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Comment: Yes but I don't have any idea how I can build working code for e.x. one selected row or more and insert values from selected row than next insert this values to my database... Propably my problem is  "foreach" but I dont know how I can write good code to do this...

Comment: @Enpeiks `print_r($row)` and post answer

Comment: Thanks but I can use my code from 1st post ? It is possible to work ?

Comment: @Enpeiks what?? i didnt get you. your `foreach` value is wrong `post('fvat')`

Comment: `insert_batch` is nothing but save your data in array form and then hit `insert_batch`....  only you need to remember is your index must be your column name..

Comment: Anybody can show me any simple code to do this ? I trying and trying and still nothing :(

Comment: print_r($this->input->post('fvat')); exit; in front of foreach, and share your output